# nodejs rest api with postgresql and passportjs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, passport.js

I'am new to NodejS and trying to implement PassportJS into my existing rest api that uses postgresql as datastore.

My code is based on this tutorial: http://mherman.org/blog/2016/03/13/designing-a-restful-api-with-node-and-postgres/#.WMBV9BLhBR1

My app.js looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var log4js = require('log4js');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var passport = require('passport')
    , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var app = express();

//For logging
var httpLogFormat = ':remote-addr - - [:date] ":method :url ' + 'HTTP/:http-version" :status :res[content-length] ' + '":referrer" ":user-agent" :response-time';
log4js.loadAppender('file');
log4js.addAppender(log4js.appenders.file('logs/access.log'), 'access');
var logger = log4js.getLogger('access');
app.use(log4js.connectLogger(logger, { level: 'auto', format: httpLogFormat }));

//Passport security
app.use(passport.initialize());



// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


//For CORS
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://example.com");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
  next();
});


app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
var callerIP = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
logger.debug("development message");
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
var callerIP = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
logger.debug("production message");
});


module.exports = app;
```

And in my queries.js I try to do the following:

```
function getAllUsers(req, res, next) {
    db.any('select * from users')
        .then(function (data) {
            res.status(200)
                .json({
                    users: data
                });
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            return next(err);
        });
}
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(options, (username, password, done) => {
    db.one('select * from users where id = $1', username)
        .then(function (data) {
            if(!data){
                return done(null, user);
            }else{
                //Generete a jwt token and return it.
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => { return done(err); });
});
```

My questions is:

Have I implemented passport correctly in my app.js?
Also the code in my queries.js failes at compile time, one of the issues iam facing is how to use the passport functionality around existing queries, for example the existing getAllUsers function and the function that fails were I try to lookup a username when trying to sign in.

My routes is placed in a index.js file:

```
router.get('/api/users', db.getAllUsers);
router.get('/api/user/:id', db.getSingleUser);
router.post('/api/users', db.createUser);
router.delete('/api/user/:id', db.deleteUser);
```

How do I encapsulate them in a passport method so some of them could only be called if the user calling them is valid?